# Where to create and how to use Enum in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have started learning iOS development.

I want to use `enum` in my sample project.

I've declared `enum` in `sample.h` like following. I hope I've declared this correctly.

```
typedef enum{s=1,m,t,w,th,f,sa} days;
```

I want to use this in `viewController.m`. In `viewController.h,` I've imported `sample.h`.

I want to use enum with the name like `"days.sa"`. But more code i searched in google, they've said like create a instance variable in `"sample.h"` like

```
@interface Sample:NSObject
{
    days d;
}
```

If I want to use this means, I need to create and use instance. But I don't want like that.

I need to use like

```
days.d or days.sa or days.th
```

How to do that ?, This must be used for the whole Project and

**How to create enum as class variable instead of instance variable ?**

Comment: yes declaring enum as static doesn't give compile error. But How to use that? I tried like following "enum days d;". But gives error.

Comment: static does not provides creating instance. you can use **days.sa**

Comment: int a=days.sa; gives compile time error

Comment: are you able to log `days.sa`?

Comment: If i write days.sa in viewController.m, it gives compile time error ..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In the enum you've created, `s`, `m` etc. are now available globally (i.e. to anything that imports `sample.h`). If you want the integer corresponding to Saturday, for example, it's just `sa`, not `days.sa`. I think you're confusing enums with structures.

For this reason, it's better to use more verbose names in your enum. Something like:

```
typedef enum
{
    WeekdaySunday = 1,
    WeekdayMonday,
    WeekdayTuesday,
    WeekdayWednesday,
    WeekdayThursday,
    WeekdayFriday,
    WeekdaySaturday
} Weekday;
```

so e.g. `WeekdayMonday` is now just another way of writing `2` in your app, but will make your code more readable and pre-defines the possible legal values for a variable of type `Weekday`.

The above is fine, but for better compiler support and to ensure the size of a `Weekday`, I'd recommend using `NS_ENUM`:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, Weekday)
{
    WeekdaySunday = 1,
    WeekdayMonday,
    WeekdayTuesday,
    WeekdayWednesday,
    WeekdayThursday,
    WeekdayFriday,
    WeekdaySaturday
};
```

Comment: What if I don't put the =1 portion. What will happen? Will the enumeration still work?

Comment: Yes, it will still work, @GeneCode. By default, it will start the enumeration from `0` instead of `1`. The only reason I chose `1` in this case was to match with the enum declared in the question.

Answer (score 10):

hey you use enum like this here is an example

In .h define enum

```
typedef enum{s=1,m,t,w,th,f,sa} days;
```

In .m play with enum element like this

```
days d1 =f;



    switch (d1) {
        case m:
        case t:
            NSLog(@"You like Tuesday");
            break;
        case w:
        case th:

            break;
        case f:
            NSLog(@"You like friday");
            break;
        case sa:
            NSLog(@"You satureday");
            break;
        case s:
            NSLog(@"You like sunday");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

if you want learn more [click](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/c-basics.html) this.

Answer (score 5):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

 typedef enum{
   s=1,m,t,w,th,f,sa
} days;

 @interface weekday : NSObject
 @property (nonatomic, assign) days day;
 @end

 @implementation weekday
 @end

 int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
 {

  @autoreleasepool {

    weekday *sunDay=[[weekday alloc]init];
    sunDay.day=s;
    NSLog(@"Today is %d",sunDay.day);

  }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating Enum in Enumrations.h

```
typedef enum  
{  
    Atype = 1,  
    Btype,  
    Ctype,
    Dtype,  
    Etype,  

}type;
```

Where ever you want to user this enum just import Enumrations.h, and you can use Atype without creating type object.

you can simply use `NSLog(@"%@",@(Atype))`.